# Defining Function With Two Variables

Tags: functions

I need to define some functions with more than one variable, but the examples only list one variable cases, so I tried this:

```
f[x_, y_] = (y/x) + xy

f[1, 2]
```

Sadly, my output is `(y/x)+xy`, which is not what I'm looking for. Someone knows what should I do?

SOLVED: had to use Exit[]

Comment: use := instead of = and read about Set and SetDelayed

Comment: Note that if you do not include a space between `x` and `y` in `xy`, the latter will be considered as an independent variable of name `xy`. This being said, defining `f[x_, y_] = (y/x) + x y` and asking for `f[1, 2]` works fine for me and returns `4`. Perhaps, exiting your session with `Exit[]` and evaluating your inputs again may solve your issue. In the general situation, it is however better to use `:=` instead of `=` as mentionned by @eldo.

Comment: Looks like using Exit[] solved the issue, thanks a lot c:

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments read about:

[Understand the difference between Set (or =) and SetDelayed (or :=)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18487#18487)

[Set](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) and [SetDelayed](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)

```
Clear[f, x, y]
f[x_, y_] := (y/x) + x*y
f[1, 2]
```

> `4`

And have a look at

[How to | Create Definitions for Variables and Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateDefinitionsForVariablesAndFunctions.html)